# Why won't my ImageMapster jquery plugin work in Power Apps portal code editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, powerapps, imagemap, imagemapster

I am trying to apply some hover effects to my image map that I have coded inside my power apps portal site via the code editor.

When I try to add in this method: `<script type="text/javascript">$('img').mapster();</script>` which sets up the styling I want, the code editor saves it as: `<script type="text/javascript">$( & #039;img&# 039;).mapster();</script>` and the jquery is not working on the page.

What do those numbers mean? Why is Power Apps adding those numbers in and is there another way to reference the image map perhaps? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Well, the numbers appear to be the html escape sequence for the apostrophe symbol. For some reason power apps is encoding them before saving (maybe to prevent code injection?). Perhaps switching them out for the double quote character can be a workaround? Double quote characters are still valid strings.

Answer (score 0):

please add this line

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"> 
</script>
```

next
append this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {
     $( & #039;img&# 039;).mapster();
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Including the jquery source will not fix the issue of that script not working.